# Circled bullets ⦿ not appearing on android WebView for API < 21

Tags: java, android, html, unicode, fonts

I'm trying to load an html file that contains the circled bullet symbol: ⦿. It's showing up fine for API 29 but doesn't seem to be working for API 21. Is there a workaround for lower APIs to fix this issue?

Comment: By using a custom font for lower APIs. And make sure that font is compatible for lower APIs too (can be loaded). Try to search one at ``xda-developers.com``.

Comment: @Darkman Thanks for the tip. Adding font face to my html file with fallback fonts fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If it might help anyone with the same/similar issue, what I did was inject @font face with fallback fonts inside my html file and specified the order in which I wanted the fonts to load - "Times New Roman" being the primary font I chose followed by "CODE2000" in case the primary font had missing glyphs. And if there were any missing glyphs still, it would fallback to an available serif font. So here, I wanted "Times New Roman" to be my primary font, but since it did not support the circled bullet glyph in API 21, a reserve font supporting the circled bullet glyph was added which fixed the issue for me.

```
<style>
  @font-face {
         font-family: 'Times New Roman';
         src: url('file:///android_asset/fonts/Times New Roman.ttf');
   }

   @font-face {
         font-family: 'Code2000';
         src: url('file:///android_asset/fonts/CODE2000.TTF');
   }

   body { font-family: 'Times New Roman', 'CODE2000', serif; }

</style>
```